# Variable inside formulaR1C1 for offseting by column using relative referencing

Tags: excel, vba

Hey this has been killing me. Look up some stuff here and found some answers that don't make sense. This is the code and it works to find a location and pull a variable from that location.

Range("G7:J7").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Test Macro'!R[-3]C[-5]"

I need to make the R[-3]C[-5] change to R[-3]C[-4] and so forth to select new data in each column. I have created a variable (macroBegin) that is used to do this. I tried many variation, but essentially, I'm trying to do this:

Range("G7:J7").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "='Test Macro'!R[-3]C[-5+(macroBegin-1)]"

What is the substitute for my poor syntax? Thanks!

Comment: If I get you right, then G7 goes for B4... H7 would be `R[-3]C[-4]`, which is D4... this way, you go for every second column... this can't be done in one step. either you want to stay with column B, then `R[-3]C2` would be your syntax, or you need to do this for each cell. Or use a formula to do this like `Range("G7:J7").FormulaR1C1 = "=INDEX('Test Macro'!R[-3],,COLUMN(R[-1]C[-6])*2)"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use,

```
Range("G7:J7").Select ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "='Test Macro'!R[-3]C[" & macroBegin - 6 & "]"
```

I believe the maths are correct there but double check; the string concatenation is right.

Comment: OMG it worked. I had to tweak the maths but the code is spot on. Dude, thanks. You have saved many many lives.